# Handler does not run after specified time

Tags: android

I am trying to restart the same Activity after a specific time say after 2 min when a button is clicked. However, it does close the activity, however does not launch in the specified time , here is the code:

```
public void snoozeup(View view)
{

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //start your activity here
            startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
        }

    }, a);      //where a is integer with value 120000

    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    voicePlayer.stop();
    voicePlayer.release();
    songPlayer.stop();
    songPlayer.release();

    this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in that way - once your Activity is finished, all UI threads are stopped. Your `Runnable` will never be called.

If you want some functionality to run when your Activity is closed, you need to create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

You should also take note of the problems with using `postDelayed` as described in [postDelayed() in a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941267/postdelayed-in-a-service).

Comment: but the activity restarts after 2 seconds after finishing it, what would be causing this then?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using:

```
public void snoozeup(View view)
{

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable x=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(Time_Date.this, Time_Date.class));
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(x, 6000);

    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    voicePlayer.stop();
    voicePlayer.release();
    songPlayer.stop();
    songPlayer.release();



    finish();
}
```